# SEO friendly URLs changes default directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

This problem concerns me for a long time. I admit that it is probably because of lack of experience so I hope I could get some ideas.

Here is the code in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view-([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

So when I access http://domain/project/view-44 it works fine, but I would like it to work with a slash in the end like http://domain/project/view-44/

So I changed the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^view-([0-9]+)/$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

And now when I access http://domain/project/view-44/ all the images, javascripts and style is gone.

Now, instead of getting the css from http://domain/project/style.css it tries to get it from http://domain/project/view-44/style.css

I believe the issue is about incorrect way of specifying url for items. In my case it is simply

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<img src="images/web/showreel.png" alt="Image1" />
```

Does that mean that I have to specify a full url ( http://domain/project/images/web/showreel.png ) in every required element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always best to specify absolute URL as this way you know the document will always be reached. I know its longwinded but instead of declaring

```
<img src='http://domain/project/images/web/showreel.png' />
```

Setup a PHP gloabal variable like

```
define('SITE_URL', ' http://domain/project');
```

Then do

```
<img src='<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/images/web/showreel.png' />
```

Also with regards to the .htaccess, take a look at http://blog.valtersboze.com/2009/06/add-or-remove-trailing-slash-in-url-with-htaccess/

This explains how to remove or keep the trailing slash, but not both, never both, google doesnt like both, they'll see it as duplicate content.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I had a clue that there is no way around except for using full url.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute paths for your resources is enough:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/project/style.css" >
<img src="/project/images/web/showreel.png" alt="Image1" />
```

Note the `/` char at the begininning. You don't need the hostname and the http part.

To avoid the differences for absolute urls between development and production you could do a simple thing. Enable virtual hosts in your apache configuration and create a virtual host for each one of your projects. In this way you don't have to use this structure in your dev environment:

```
http://localhost/project1
http://localhost/project2
```

but you can use urls like these

```
http://project1/
http://project2/
```

In this way your problem is solved and you can use url's like `/images` for your resources.

To enable virtual host for apache you'll need to tweak dns configuration for your machine by adding these lines to your [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file

```
127.0.0.1 project1
127.0.0.1 project2
```

and then you'll need to create [corresponding virtual hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/236564/virtual-host-debian-apach2/236570#236570)

Comment: That would fix the problem for a while, but when I go from my local server to a project dedicated server, the project will be in root directory. Then I would have to edit every link.

Comment: Your development environment should be similar to your production to avoid this kind of issues. I'll update the answer with a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The easy workaround is to use

```
<base href="/index">
```

in the `<head>` of your HTML templates. Thus all the resource links become relative to the root directory again, independent of the virtual RewriteRule structure.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-base-element

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the head of the document:

```
<base href="http://domain/project/" />
```

This is necessary becausee the client's browser has no way of knowing the rewritten URL, it is only known on the server side.